# How to create a bitmap from another bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3

Let´s say I have a bitmap with 3 colors: red, green and blue (not mixed)

What if I wanted to make a bitmap of the red part of the first bitmap?

I´d like to take the red pixels from first bitmap (and its positions), and make another bitmap.

Is that possible?

Comment: I am not sure whether you are talking about colors the way that you have picture with blue, red and green parts or the way that every color is defined by mixing three colours - red, green and blue.

Comment: I just want to get the red pixels from a bitmap and make a new bitmap from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`BitmapData.copyChannel()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyChannel%28%29) to copy a single channel's color information into a new BitmapData object.

Something like this (untested):

```
//myBitmap is the source bitmap
var oldBMD:BitmapData = myBitmap.bitmapData;
var newBMD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(oldBMD.width,oldBMD.height,true,0);
oldBmd.copyChannel(newBMD, null, null, BitmapDataChannel.RED, BitmapDataChannel.RED);
var newBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(newBMD);
```

Answer (score 2):

As and addition to solution posted by shanethehat, I will point you to this amazing class called - [colormatrix](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000565.php), written by SO user [quasimondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111030/quasimondo). It gives you more efficient way to work with channels in the action script. And if you are going to work with bitmap and graphics in general you can checkout the  [Quasimondo Libs](http://code.google.com/p/quasimondolibs/source/checkout) from google code repository.